# Suggested to use recursive or non-recursive mappings to normalize mapping

Tags: vimrc

What approach would be preferred to allow a `cmd-s` to trigger a save, regardless of mode:

```
" Allow i,c to call normal mode
noremap  <leader>S    :silent call SaveFile()<CR>asdfidfo
inoremap <leader>S    <C-O><leader>S
cnoremap <leader>S    <C-c><leader>S
```

Or, everyone for themselves:

```
noremap  <leader>S         :silent call SaveFile()<CR>
inoremap <leader>S    <C-o>:silent call SaveFile()<CR>
cnoremap <leader>S    <C-c>:silent call SaveFile()<CR>
```

Why would one approach be preferred over another?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a very personal, mapping I'd go with either solution 2,

```
" For instance I have
nnoremap <silent> <C-s> :<c-u>update<CR>
inoremap <silent> <C-s> <c-o>:update<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <C-s> <c-c>:update<CR>gv
```

or use non-nore mappings (corrected solution 1).

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-s> :<c-u>update<CR>
imap     <silent> <C-s> <c-o><c-s>
vmap     <silent> <C-s> <c-c><c-s>gv
```

BTW, the visual mappings are incorrect, and normal mode will need to clear possible counts.

For distributed pluggins, I use plug-mappings and I even define helper functions and commands to define several mappings (and menus) at once.